# How to name a C++ capture variable?

Tags: c++, lambda

I am only interested to pass by reference the third element of `arr` into the lambda capture expression. Is it possible to do this without the `int &value = arr[2];` in the snippet below?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <condition_variable>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> arr = {3,1,4};

    std::cout << &arr[2] << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> vfunc;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int a = i * 2;
        int &value = arr[2];
        std::function<void()> fn = [=,&value](){
            //std::cout << a << std::endl; 
            std::cout << &value << std::endl;
        };

        vfunc.push_back(fn);
    }

    for (auto& f : vfunc) 
    {
        f();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only since C++14.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can accomplish it via [by-reference capture](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) specified with the initializer.

> & identifier initializer  (6) (since C++14)
>
> 6) by-reference capture with an initializer

e.g.

```
std::function<void()> fn = [=,&value=arr[2]](){
//                                  ^^^^^^^
    //std::cout << a << std::endl; 
    std::cout << &value << std::endl;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do this without the `int &value = arr[2];`?

Yes, you can add named references to the closure and initialize them like this:

```
std::function<void()> fn = [=, &value = arr[2]](){ /* ... */ }
```

Not that this requires C++14 to be available. If C++17 can be used, for your particular lambda body that doesn't modify `arr[2]`, you might also consider adding `const`-ness:

```
std::function<void()> fn = [=,&value = std::as_const(arr[2])](){ /* ... */ }
                                      //^^^^^^^^^^^^ verbose but useful
```

Comment: Note that it is trivial to use a non-standard implementation of `as_const` in case C++-17 is unavailable.